# Noun phrase modified or raised

Tags: phrase-meaning

> As he sat in the usual morning traffic jam, he couldn’t help noticing
>   that there seemed to be a lot of strangely dressed people about.
>   People in cloaks. Mr. Dursley couldn’t bear people who dressed in
>   funny clothes — **the getups you saw on young people!** He supposed
>   this was some stupid new fashion. He drummed his fingers on the
>   steering wheel and his eyes fell on a huddle of these weirdos standing
>   quite close by. (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Can the highlighted part be parsed as one of the following?

1. Noun phrase + relative clause (modifying NP) + prepositional phrase (modifying NP)
2. *The getups* is raised for emphasizing (plus, does *on* mean [preposition #2 on Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on#Preposition)?)

Comment: The dash marks it as outside the syntax of the first clause: it's a quote (albeit backshifted) from Mr. Dursley's 'interior monologue'.

Comment: _All the promises we made._

Comment: *The questions you see on ELL!* I have no idea what the linguistics term [raising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_(linguistics)) has to do with the question (which I freely admit I don't understand *at all*).

Comment: @ Listenever :Can you provide the link to this paragraph or from where have you taken this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down... it's been here a while so I will take a shot at it.

Can the highlighted be parsed as one of the following:

1. Noun phrase + relative clause (modifying NP) + prepositional phrase (modifying NP)
   A: I do not believe so.  I think what we're looking at here is an ***[exclamatory phrase](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exclamation)*** which is a type of sentence fragment and does not necessarily follow any rule of parsing.  In this passage, Mr. Dursley is feeling exasperation over the crazy clothes kids are wearing these days, and lets his feelings be known in this exclamation.
2. a) *The getups* is raised for emphasizing.
   A: I do not believe this is an example of [raising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_%28linguistics%29).
   b) Plus, does *on* mean preposition #2 on [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on#Preposition)?
   A: Yes, you are correct here.  The word "getups" means, loosely, clothing or manner of dress.  It is usually used when the speaker does not understand or cannot relate to the style of dress being observed.  Substitute "clothing" for "getups" and your preposition *on* (to cover) makes perfect sense. :)